# calculating the foot steps used by the user using ionic and ngcordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova, healthkit

I am trying to do an app like calculating foot steps used by the user for example like see [move](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.protogeo.moves) and [google fit - fitness](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.fitness)
app available in play store.

After surfing a google i found a tutorial using  [pedometer](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-pedometer) but i would like create an app only with the mobile device with GPS detection or sensor like that i have tried searching using accelerate but i don't know how to use it any tips in this part please.

My Requirement is just to calculate the number of foot steps user used after click the button and to stop calculating the foot steps after clicking the stop button.

I did not found any plugin or blog or example app in ionic help me if some one know about this.

Comment: I m not familiar with Ionic framework. But after having a quick look, these are links i got which may be helpful - https://github.com/texh/cordova-plugin-stepcounter http://kingsfleet.blogspot.in/2015/02/hows-many-steps-did-i-walk-yesterday.html https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-pedometer

Comment: @Gandhi thanks for you reply but i need to detect the foot steps only with device like as i explained in my question and also the pedometer is working only with ios8+ device and very advanced android devices

Comment: Have you tried Ionic's Official Libraries for StepCounter and PedoMeter? They work awesome for your app Here's the links :-
[Ionic StepCounter](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/stepcounter/) [Ionic PedoMeter](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/pedometer/) And of Course a good tutorial :-
[PedoMeter with Ionic](https://mbrowndev.com/how-to-build-a-pedometer-app-with-ionic/)

Answer (score 2):

When the user starts the journey get their GPS location. Then at an interval (probably around 5 to 10 seconds) get their new GPS location. Build these locations into a list. geoJSON http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html defines a good data structure for storing these. It will end up looking something like this:

```
 { "type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
  { "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [102.0, 0.0], [103.0, 1.0], [104.0, 0.0], [105.0, 1.0]
        ]
      }

   ]
 }
```

There are quite a few libraries that can take this format and turn it into a total distance. Google Maps Api is one of them I believe. My favourite is Postgis (http://postgis.net/). If you set up a back end service to store the work outs you can use Postgis to store this "LineString" object (http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Length.html). The one thing to be sure of is that the reference (SRID) you use with Postgis is the same that you are collecting from the device. I would guess it would be 4326.

Once you have a distance finding the number of steps is a function of the users step length

```
#steps = distance / step length.
```

Comment: i am not able to follow you can you give me some brief explanation and step by step instruction and what GPS library and how to make use in ionic need some good explanation for every one to follow

Answer (score 1):

counting steps can be tricky as **GPS is not 100% accurate**. but you can do the following.

use [geolocation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-geolocation) plugin and add a watch position which gives lat-long every 2 seconds or so. but it won't  work when app is in background. so add [background task plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) and add [geolocation.watchPosition](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-geolocation#navigatorgeolocationwatchposition) code inside it. see [this question and answer for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36853475/how-to-make-a-phonegap-application-save-current-geolocation-less-often/36865767#36865767)

or you can use [background geolocation plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation) if it suits your requirement

test it and determine how much steps user can take in that 2 or 1 second timeout. set counter in `watchPosition`'s success callback and keep adding that value you determined.

**keep in mind that this could not be accurate as you are relying on GPS.**
besides this logic can fail if user runs or walks faster than normal speed consider adding more sensor support to get accurate results.

Comment: is there any other way without gps how does the **move** app in play store works accurately can you help me

Comment: @MohanGopi sure thing. moving [conversation to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112568/android-hybrid-pedometer)

Comment: come to chat for further discussion